# Performance/standard using 1d vs 2d vectors in numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, linear-algebra

Is there a standard practice for representing vectors as 1d or 2d ndarrays in NumPy?  I'm moving from MATLAB which represents vectors as 2d arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, 1D is the norm in numpy for vectors. The only good reason to keep a vector of `n` elements as a 2D array of shape `(1, n)` or `(n, 1)` is in a linear algebra context, where you wanted to keep row and column vectors differentiated. As EitanT hinted on his now deleted answer, you would probably then want to use numpy's `matrix` type, which keeps 2D shape of returns except for single element access, e.g if `a` has shape `(m, n)` then `a[0]` has shape `(n,)` for type `ndarray`, but shape `(1, n)` for type  `matrix`, although `a[0, 0]` returns a scalar in both cases.

If you stick with 1D vector of shape `(n,)`, you can reshape on the fly for specific operations requiring the 2D shape:

```
a.reshape(-1, 1) # shape (n, 1)
a[:, None] # shape (n, 1)
a.reshape(1, -1) # shape (1, n)
a[None, :] # shape (1, n)
```

Numpy will automatically reshape your 1D vectors to shape `(1, n)` when [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) it for an operation with a 2D array involved.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the differences.  My main concern is having potentially bad matrix multiplications pass without error.  http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935 shows matrix types have a some downsides which outweigh be benefits of overloading the '*' operator.

Answer (score 1):

In matlab (for historical reason I would argue) the basic type is an `M`-by-`N` array (matrix) so that scalars are 1-by-1 arrays and vectors either `N`-by-1 or 1-by-`N` arrays. (Memory layout is always Fortran style).

This "limitation" is not present in `numpy`: you have true scalars and `ndarray`'s can have as many dimensions you like. (Memory layout can be C or Fortran-contigous.) For this reason there is no preferred (standard) practice. It is up to you, according to your application, to choose the one which better suits your needs.